# ExtJS 4.2 "filefield" Choose File button UI rendering weirdly

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd, filefield

I want a simple Extjs Document upload panel. I used this [example available on Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/form/file-upload.html). I was expecting something like this

[image]

But when I implement the same example as it is, my panel is displayed like this (save image is due to something I was trying).

[image]

Issue is with Choose file button. I know that sencha example is using some kind of CSS but I am trying to put Image as back grounds via css but that is not helping as well(If I set "icon" property in Button config, even then the button remain the same size).

This is my code

```
{
    xtype: 'form',
    padding: '5 5 5 5',
    flex: 1,
    frame: false,
    border: false,
    title: 'File Upload Form',
    bodyPadding: '50 10 0',

    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%',
        allowBlank: false,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        labelWidth: 50
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Name'
    },{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        id: 'form-file',
        emptyText: 'Select an image',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        name: 'photo-path',
        buttonText: '',
        buttonConfig: {
            iconCls: "background:url(http://simonwai.com/images/save_icon.gif) no-repeat !important; border:none;"
            //icon: "http://simonwai.com/images/save_icon.gif",
        }
    }],

     buttons: [{
        //text: 'Save',
        icon: "http://simonwai.com/images/save_icon.gif",
        handler: function(){
            /*var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if(form.isValid()){
                form.submit({
                    url: 'file-upload.php',
                    waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                    success: function(fp, o) {
                        msg('Success', tpl.apply(o.result));
                    }
                });
            }*/
        }
    },{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            //this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }]
    }
```

kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/s46) your code is correct for ExtJS 4.2.

What you should do is to use styles from one of the Sencha provided themes or to extend one of them.

Comment: That's not helping man. I am using Sencha Grey theme. I don't understand that why should apply style for this button. 
Kindly give me an example of what you mean.

Comment: Look at the fiddle, your code + sencha gray theme style do not correspond to your screenshot. Probably you have some override/customization so your filefield does not use theme styles.

Comment: I don't have a custom theme. In .Sencha/app/sencha.cfg my theme is set to Sencha Grey theme. So I haven't applied any sort of customization theme wise.

Comment: Federico, when you said that I was using custom theme, I remembered that I tried to implement custom theme once but I reverted back all the changes after that . 
I just build app again after setting it back to classic theme and everything worked like a charms. 
Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

though this question is a bit old...

I came here having the same issue. After running "sencha app build" the file control was rendered properly. Guess the build process needed to add some styles that weren't available in the development mode before a fresh app build that had the file control in its `requires`.